# One post auto attached to many another items

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, tags

Let's say I'm building site with mp3's. I'm adding every single mp3 as custom-post-type. I 'm also adding artists bio and its displayed on every single-mp3 post. What I want to do is add this bio just once and I want it do display automatically on every single-mp3 page of this artist. How should I bite this problem? Let's say I will add artist name in tags. Can I use tags to display just bio from some other place? Honestly have no idea how to even look for solution for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I would tackle this would be with a custom taxonomy, maybe hierarchical, depends on the implementation. I would use the description field on the taxonomy terms to store the artist's name, etc. If you need a more robust implementation with greater flexibility, creating the artists as another custom post type then using a dropdown or even a manual entry field on the song to select the artist would be my goto.